# Caliburn.Micro: logging every ActionMessage?

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics, caliburn.micro

We're starting a new Silverlight project on Caliburn.Micro.  We need to log every user interaction through Google Analytics.  Is there any way to have a bit of code executed every time any ActionMessage is sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, this is quite easy. Replace ActionMessage.InvokeAction with your own method which does logging and then calls the original. You will want to do this in the Bootstrapper's Configure override. Your code would look something like this:

```
var originalInvoke = ActionMessage.InvokeAction
ActionMessage.InvokeAction = context => {
    //do logging here using the context
    originalInvoke(context);
}
```

That's all there is to it. From the context variable you can get the MethodInfo, the Taget view model, the View, the EventArgs and the Source element that triggered the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but `ActionMessage` has an `InvokeAction` public delegate, so you could subscribe to that invocation list, perhaps in your bootstrapper's `Configure` method:

```
ActionMessage.InvokeAction +=
  c => { throw new Exception(string.Format("Method '{0}' invoked", c.Method.Name)); };
```

You'll recieve an `ActionExecutionContext` which will give you information about the action.

Perhaps do something more useful than throwing an exception :)